# how to take input in python when no of input are not defined

Tags: python, input

this is an c++ code , how can I implement this in python ?

```
while(scanf("%lld",&n)!=EOF)
    {
        cout<<convert(n)<<endl;
    }
```

Comment: Can you please explain what the code supposed to do for those who are not familiar with C++?

Answer (score 0):

This is roughly equivalent:

```
def convert(input):
     #do something with your input

import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    convert(int(line))
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, instead of using `scanf` and friends, usually you read a line or an entire file into a string, and use string operations to get the results you want.

In your example, you could do something like:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    for word in line.split():
        number = int(word)

        ... = convert(number)
```

Answer (score 0):

it can be done using try except

link below can be used

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38621838/4557946