# python take input when number of input is not specified

Tags: python, eof

I am new to python and trying to solve a problem in SPOJ ,

In this question number of input(maximum 10 is specified, how ever it could be anything between 1 to 10) is not specified 
hence it gives NZEC error

I tried this:

```
t = 10
while(t>0):
   t = t - 1 
   n = raw_input()
   if(len(n) == 0):
      break
```

but it does not work

in c we can use EOF to determine this

please help

Comment: Please fix the indentation and detail the error

Comment: What are you trying to do here?  Take 10 different inputs?  what are you doing with `n` that is typed by the user?  What exactly is this code meant to achieve?

Comment: maximum of 10 inputs so it can be anything between 1 to 10 ... my question is what if only 5 input or 7 how do i know when to stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved 
Use

```
try:
   while True:
       n = int(raw_input())
       #do something
except:
   pass
```